# How to forward a mouse event from a glasspane to a jpopupmenu

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, dispatchevent, glasspane

I am experimenting on capturing all the mouse events and based on some logic dispatch them to the related components. The capturing occurs with the use of a glasspane which captures all mouse events and then I calculate the component that should be underneath the glasspane to dispatch the event to it. This works okay for buttons but is impossible to work for JPopupmenus, not sure why I tried different approaches but couldn't get the reference of the JPopupmenu or once of its items.

Here is a minimum working example,
click on the button and see that it works okay
click on the jpopupmenu that was displayed from prev step
and notice that the jpanel is clicked.

```
public class GlassPaneExample2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Glass Pane Example");
        frame.setSize(400, 300);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Button 2 txt");
        button.addActionListener(e -> showPopupMenu(button));
        mainPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        GlassPane glassPane = new GlassPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.setGlassPane(glassPane);
        glassPane.setVisible(true);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void showPopupMenu(Container container) {
        JPopupMenu jPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Menu Item 1");
        JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Menu Item 2");
        menuItem1.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(container, "Menu Item 1 selected"));
        menuItem2.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(container, "Menu Item 2 selected"));
        jPopupMenu.add(menuItem1);
        jPopupMenu.add(menuItem2);
        jPopupMenu.show(container, 100, 10);
    }


}

class GlassPane extends JComponent {
    static Component findComponentUnderGlassPane(JComponent glassPane, Point glassPaneEventPoint, Container contentPane) {
        Point containerPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(glassPane, glassPaneEventPoint, contentPane);

    if (containerPoint.y >= 0) {
            return SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt(contentPane, containerPoint.x, containerPoint.y);
        }
        return null;
    }
    void dispatch(MouseEvent mouseEvent, Container container) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Component component = findComponentUnderGlassPane(GlassPane.this, mouseEvent.getPoint(), container);
            if (component != null && !component.equals(GlassPane.this)) {
                System.out.println("Dispatching to " + component.getClass().getSimpleName() + "#" + component.hashCode());
                component.dispatchEvent(SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(GlassPane.this, mouseEvent, component));
            }
        });
    }
    public GlassPane(Container contentPane) {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatch(e, contentPane);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: AWT/Swing has already implemented the process of identifying the component under the mouse cursor and pass the event to it. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: its part of the implementation of an in-content scrolling feature I am working on, the glass pane was used to avoid clicking buttons or selecting UI components if the intent was to drag.